# I'm trying install rpm package but i not able to install rpm

Tags: oracle, rpm

I'm using CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final) but unable install given package

1) rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Whenever i install package,I got following error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
            oracle-instantclient11.2-basic >= 11.2.0.1.0 is needed by oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64
```

2)rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Whenever i install package,I got following error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        oracle-instantclient11.2-basic >= 11.2.0.1.0 is needed by oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the instant client information page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html):

> **Installation Instructions**
>
> Installation Steps:
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations REQUIRE the Basic or Basic Lite package.
>      ...

That is referring to the `.zip` version, but the same will apply to the `.rpm` version.

So you need to get and install the `oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` or `oracle-instantclient11.2-basiclite-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` (Basic Lite: Smaller version of the Basic, with only English error messages and Unicode, ASCII, and Western European character set support) before you can install the `-devel-` package on top.

Kind of curious that you're installing the 11.2.0.1 version (or 11.2.0.3 from your first error message, despite the command you showed) when more recent versions are available. I assume you're getting your `.rpm` files from [the download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html). I'd get the 11.2.0.4 version, if not the 12.0.0.1 version, unless you have a specific reason to stick to an older one. I would get the same version for `basic` and `devel` though, despite the message suggesting they don't have to match. So `oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm` (or `basiclite`) if you're sticking with `oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm`.